# Google spreadsheet mail as Excel attachment

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I want to mail Google Spreadsheet as excel attachment, and also I want to write
4 to 5 lines in the body of a mail, and also I want to send this mail to many peoples some in "To", and some in "Cc" can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easier way is that you send the spreadsheet as Excel attachment to yourself, then send use your email client to compose the email (add people to TO, CC, write the 4-5 lines in the body)

To do this,

1. Open your spreadsheet
2. Clic on File > Email as attachment
3. On the dialog, on **Attach as** select **Microsoft Excel**
4. On **TO** write your email address
5. Click **Send**

Then on your email client, you could use the Forward feature to create a new email including the Excel attachment.